# Actor Exception

Tags: groovy, actor, gpars

I just want to send some messages between 2 actors in Groovy.
I receive the first messages `abc`, but get then the following exception:

> An exception occurred in the Actor thread Actor Thread 1
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: act1 for class: groovyx.gpars.actor.DefaultActor

Here is my code:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.actor.Actors.actor

def act2 = actor {
    react {
        println it
        act1.send "def"
    }
}

def act1 = actor {
    act2.send 'abc'
    react { println it }
}

[act1, act2]*.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing

```
def act1, act2
```

At the top of your script after the import statement

Then remove the 2 `def` keywords you currently have

Comment: Do you also know, if it's possible to send and handle several messages at once? `act1.send "abc" act1.send 5` and `act1` then just prints out `abc` and, for example, calculates the `5` with 3 and returns 8?